# IIS deployment on non-server (consumer) Window versions is advisable?

Tags: iis, licensing

We have a WCF Service that we either have to host in a Windows Service or IIS. This is a commercial application that will be installed on consumer pc's running for example Win7 Home.

In my opinion IIS on Win7 is by Microsoft only meant for development and/or testing. Activating IIS on a consumer pc shouldn't be a real option.

So my question is: Is it a real option to host a WCF service in IIS in a commercial application on a simple consumer pc?

Comment: For those scenarios Microsoft gives you the option to self host without IIS.

Comment: true, but the question is I'm (still) looking on deployment info of IIS on non-server Windows environments